# CMake error when trying to install Multinest

Tags: c++, makefile, gfortran

I've been trying to install Multinest on my laptop (MacBook Air M1) following this guide:https://johannesbuchner.github.io/PyMultiNest/install.html#prerequisites-for-building-the-libraries

However, when running the `cmake ..` I'm left with the following error message:

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info
-- Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working Fortran compiler: /opt/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-gfortran
-- Check for working Fortran compiler: /opt/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-gfortran - broken
CMake Error at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.25.0/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeTestFortranCompiler.cmake:62 (message):
  The Fortran compiler
"/opt/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-gfortran"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

Change Dir: /Users/myname/Documents/MultiNest/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-JLpNaW

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make -f Makefile cmTC_38eb9/fast && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_38eb9.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_38eb9.dir/build
Building Fortran object CMakeFiles/cmTC_38eb9.dir/testFortranCompiler.f.o
/opt/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-gfortran   -march=nocona -mtune=core2 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector -O2 -pipe  -c /Users/myname/Documents/MultiNest/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-JLpNaW/testFortranCompiler.f -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_38eb9.dir/testFortranCompiler.f.o
Linking Fortran executable cmTC_38eb9
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.25.0/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_38eb9.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/opt/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-gfortran -march=nocona -mtune=core2 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector -O2 -pipe  CMakeFiles/cmTC_38eb9.dir/testFortranCompiler.f.o -o cmTC_38eb9 
ld: library not found for -lSystem
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [cmTC_38eb9] Error 1
make: *** [cmTC_38eb9/fast] Error 2





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

/sudo



is not a full path to an existing compiler tool.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
```

I've tried to export the C/C++ compiler paths but it hasn't helped.